# Can Object pool design pattern cause memory shortage?

Tags: design-patterns

When I am using the Object pool design pattern, and allowing the pool to grow, by creating new objects when they are required but not available in the pool, and placing them in the pool after they have been used, can it eventually cause memory shortage, or some kind of an out of memory exception/error?

It looks very reasonable that after some time it will happen, because the pool grows, and the object within it don't get deleted.

Comment: Every form of memory management has the possibility for mismanagement. Some just make mismanagement more obvious.

Answer (score 7):

The obvious solution is to not let the pool grow too large.

If your Object Pool works as it should, your program should already be releasing objects back into the pool when they are no longer needed, so that they can be reused.  If your pool is growing unbounded, that means your Object Pool is not managing the objects properly, or your program is simply designed in such a way that it's using too many objects or not releasing those objects when it is done with them.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is a little bit tautological. Exaggerated, you are essentially asking: "If I keep allocating memory, and never give it back, will I keep allocating memory and never give it back?" To which the answer is obviously "Yes, if you keep allocating memory, and never give it back, you will keep allocating memory and never give it back!"

There are two obvious solutions to this:

1. Don't keep allocating memory.
2. Give memory back.

With regards to #1, the idea of an Object Pool is that you *don't* create new objects but rather re-use the ones that are already in the pool. If you re-use objects, you will obviously not allocate new ones, so this solves the problem from that direction.

With regards to #2, this would mean that you remove objects from the pool. A variation would be that you use weak references for the objects in the pool, so that the memory management system can reclaim them by itself (assuming that you are using a language that has a memory management system).

In a language with automatic memory management, it is often an option to not use Object Pooling at all. People often underestimate how fantastically good modern high-performance garbage collectors are. 25 years ago, Sun's JVM did not have a very good GC, so there is high-performance code out there from those days that uses Object Pooling.

Modern GCs are much, much better than those from 25 years ago, and Object Pools are actually a worst-case for modern GCs. Modern GCs are based on the Generational Hypothesis: most objects die young, old objects don't reference new objects, objects are not mutated. An Object Pool keeps objects alive artificially, because objects are re-used, it is highly likely that older objects will reference new ones, and of course in order to re-use objects, you generally mutate them.

So, it is entirely possible that not only is the Object Pool an unnecessary complication because maybe the GC would do a good job by itself, but the Object Pool might actually be hurting the GC.

Comment: In my experience, object pooling is most often used in context of object creation from a database, so it can prevent unnecessary database queries. That works regardless of the availability of high-performance memory management.